# Drop not null constraint for joinColumns in JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity, leaning on which hibernate able to generate join table for OneToMany-relations.

```
@Entity
public class RequestType extends EntityObject {
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "MType_MType", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mtype_id"), 
   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inner_request_types_id"))
   private List<LogicalInnerType> innerRequestTypes;
 }

@Entity
public class EntityObject {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EntityID")
  private Integer id;
 }
```

But when I run application, I receive the following exception:

> PSQLException: EROOR: null value in column "inner_request_types_id" violate constraint NOT NULL

As I know, any JoinColumn has a default true of nullable-parameter.

How could I otherwise drop notnull-constraint?

Comment: What should be the purpose of row of the join table if there are null values?

Comment: Seems to me like the null values shouldn't be there in the first place. I would remove them and keep the constraints

Comment: In what meaning you removed them?...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default value of `JoinColumn.nullable()` is `true`:

```
/** (Optional) Whether the foreign key column is nullable. */
boolean nullable() default true;
```

But this is not relevant here, because `nullable()` is not inspected for `@JoinColumn` in a `@OneToMany`. Hibernate will always add a *not null* constraint to both columns, because it expects that there is always an owning entity and that the list never contains null values.

If you wanted to add `null` values to your list in the first place (and this is not a mistake), you should think about an alternative. For example you could add a boolean attribute to `RequestType` that indicates the state that you wanted to achieve with the `null` value.

By the way there is another thing, that is apparently not correct in your model. You are using a `List`, but you add no `@OrderColumn`. As a result Hibernate has no possibility to ensure any order. If you really want to store a specific order, you should add an `@OrderColumn` annotation. Or you use a `Set` instead.